# Java method overloading - Generic parameter & parameters within same inheritance tree

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, overloading

Let's assume I have following code:

```
// Method acception generic parameter
public static <T> T foo(T para) {
    return para;
}

// Method accepting Integer parameter
public static Integer foo(Integer para) {
    return para + 1;
}

// Method accepting Number parameter
public static Number foo(Number para) {
    return para.intValue() + 2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Float f = new Float(1.0f);
    Integer i = new Integer(1);
    Number n = new Integer(1);
    String s = "Test";

    Number fooedFloat = foo(f);     // Uses foo(Number para)
    Number fooedInteger = foo(i);   // Uses foo(Integer para)
    Number fooedNumber = foo(n);    // Uses foo(Number para)
    String fooedString = foo(s);    // Uses foo(T para)

    System.out.println("foo(f): " + fooedFloat);
    System.out.println("foo(i): " + fooedInteger);
    System.out.println("foo(n): " + fooedNumber);
    System.out.println("foo(s): " + fooedString);
}
```

The output looks the following:

```
foo(f): 3
foo(i): 2
foo(n): 3
foo(s): Test
```

Now the question(s):

1. `foo(n)` calls `foo(Number para)`, most probably because `n` is defined as `Number`, even though it has an `Integer` assigned to it. So am I right in the assumption that the decision, which of the overloaded methods is taken happens at compile-time, without dynamic binding? (Question about *static* and *dynamic* binding)
2. `foo(f)` uses `foo(Number para)`, while `foo(i)` uses `foo(Integer para)`. Only `foo(s)` uses the generic version. So the compiler always looks if there is a non-generic implementation for the given types, and only if not it falls back to the generic version? (Question about *generics*)
3. Again, `foo(f)` uses `foo(Number para)`, while `foo(i)` uses `foo(Integer para)`. Yet, `Integer i` would also be a `Number`. So always the method with the "outer-most" type within the inheritance tree is taken? (Question about *inheritance*)

I know these are a lot questions, and the example is not taken from productive code, yet I just would like to know what "happens behind" and why things happen.

Also any links to the Java documentation or the Java specification are really appreciated, I could not find them myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules of determining which method signature to call at compile-time are explained in the [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2). Specifically important is the section on choosing [the most specific method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5). Here are the parts related to your questions:

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the *most specific* method is chosen.
>
> ...
>
> One applicable method `m1` is more specific than another applicable method `m2`, for an invocation with argument expressions `e1`, ..., `ek`, if any of the following are true:
>
> - `m2` is generic, and `m1` is inferred to be more specific than `m2` for argument expressions `e1`, ..., `ek` by §18.5.4.
> - `m2` is not generic, and `m1` and `m2` are applicable by strict or loose invocation, and where `m1` has formal parameter types S1, ..., Sn and `m2` has formal parameter types T<sub>1</sub>, ..., T<sub>n</sub>, the type S<sub>i</sub> is more specific than T<sub>i</sub> for argument `ei` for all *i* (1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n*, *n* = *k*).
>
> ...
>
> A type S is *more specific* than a type T for any expression if S <: T (§4.10).

In this case, `Integer` is more specific than `Number` because `Integer` extends `Number`, so whenever the compiler detects a call to `foo` that takes a variable *declared* of type `Integer`, it will add an invocation for `foo(Integer)`.

More about the first condition related to the second method being generic is explained in [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.4). It's a little verbose but I think the important part is:

> When testing that one applicable method is *more specific* than another (§15.12.2.5), where the second method is generic, it is necessary to test whether some instantiation of the second method's type parameters can be inferred to make the first method more specific than the second.
>
> ...
>
> Let `m1` be the first method and `m2` be the second method. Where `m2` has type parameters P<sub>1</sub>, ..., P<sub>p</sub>, let α<sub>1</sub>, ..., α<sub>p</sub> be inference variables, and let θ be the substitution [P<sub>1</sub>:=α<sub>1</sub>, ..., P<sub>p</sub>:=α<sub>p</sub>].
>
> ...
>
> The process to determine if `m1` is more specific than `m2` is as follows:
>
> ...
>
> If T<sub>i</sub> is a proper type, the result is *true* if S<sub>i</sub> is more specific than T<sub>i</sub> for e<sub>i</sub> (§15.12.2.5), and *false* otherwise. (Note that S<sub>i</sub> is always a proper type.)

Which basically means that `foo(Number)` and `foo(Integer)` are both more specific than `foo(T)` because the compiler can infer at least one type for the generic method (e.g. `Number` itself) that makes `foo(Number)` and `foo(Integer)` more specific (this is because `Integer <: Number` and `Number <: Number`) .

This also means that in your code `foo(T)` is only applicable (and inherently the most specific method since it's only the one applicable) for the invocation that passes a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I right in the assumption that the decision, which of the overloaded methods is taken happens at compile-time, without dynamic binding?

Yes, Java chooses among available overloads of a method at compile time, based on the declared types of the arguments, from among the alternatives presented by the declared type of the target object.

Dynamic binding applies to choosing among methods having the *same* signature based on the runtime type of the invocation target.  It has nothing directly to do with the runtime types of the actual arguments.

> So the compiler always looks if there is a non-generic implementation for the given types, and only if not it falls back to the generic version?

Because of type erasure, the actual signature of your generic method is

```
Object foo(Object);
```

Of the argument types you tested, that is the best match among the overloaded options only for the `String`.

> So always the method with the "outer-most" type within the inheritance tree is taken?

More or less.  When selecting among overloads, the compiler chooses the alternative that best matches the declared argument types.  For a single argument of reference type, this is the method whose argument type is the argument's declared type, or its nearest supertype.

Things can get dicey if Java has to choose among overloads of multiple-argument methods, and it doesn't have an exact match.  When there are primitive arguments, it also has to consider the allowed argument conversions.  The full details take up a largish section of the JLS.

Answer (score 1):

So, it is pretty simple:

1) Yes, the decision is made at compile-time. The compiler chooses the method with the most specific matching type. So the compiler will choose the `Number` version when the variable you pass as an argument is declared as a `Number`, even if it is an `Integer` at run-time. (If the compiler finds two "equally matching" methods, an ambiguous method error will make the compilation fail)

2) At run-time, there are no generics, everything is just an `Object`. Generics are a compile-time and source-code feature only. Therefore the compiler must do the best he can, because the VM surely can not.